# Best Way to Parse this app_data String Format with PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, string, parsing

Given a facebook URL with this format:

`....&app_data=eid~423423|pid~23982938|admin~1`

I want an array:

`[ 'eid' => '423423', 'pid => '23982938', 'admin' => '1' ];`

This is how I'm doing it:

`$app_data = $signed_request['app_data'];
parse_str(str_replace('~','=',str_replace('|','&',$app_data)), $app_data_params);`

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: app_data=eid~423423 gives app_data => 424423? What about the eid - is that really silently dropped?

Comment: There is nothing wrong at all with the way you're doing it, and frankly it is better than either suggestion you've received thus far.

Comment: It is better, I thought that someone would give a regexp solution to replace the two str_replace.

Comment: Eh. There's nothing magical about regex, if you benchmarked `str_replace` vs. `preg_replace`, I **think** you'd find that the more simple `str_replace` will out-perform the regex function.... over five hundred thousand iterations by a factor of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` to eliminate the two calls to `str_replace`, but I doubt you'd see any performance benefit to doing so. There's nothing wrong with the way you're already doing it.

```
$str = 'eid~423423|pid~23982938|admin~1';
parse_str(
    preg_replace(
        array('/\~/','/\|/'), 
        array('=','&'), 
        $str
    ), 
    $app_data_params
);
print_r($app_data_params);
// Array ( [eid] => 423423 [pid] => 23982938 [admin] => 1 )
```

**Documentation**

- `preg_replace` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
- `parse_str` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 0):

Try explode()

```
$appData = explode("|", $signed_request['app_data']);
```

That will at least give you

```
array(3) {
    [0] => "eid~4234234",
    [1] => "pid~23982398",
    [2] => "admin~1"
}
```

Comment: This does not produce the associative array that the OP specified as their goal. It also fails to parse the serialized elements of the data array.

Comment: @chris I mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['app_data']= "eid~423423|pid~23982938|admin~1";

$a = str_replace('~','=', $_GET['app_data']);
$b = str_replace("|","&", $a);
parse_str($b);

echo $eid;
echo $pid;
echo $admin;
```

There is another way. Gaaah, @Chris beat me to it!

Answer (score -1):

```
//  incoming GET string
$_GET['app_data']= "eid~423423|pid~23982938|admin~1";

$bits = explode("|", $_GET['app_data']);

foreach( $bits as $bit ){
$res = explode('~', $bit);
$result[$res[0]] = $res[1];
}

var_dump($result);
array
'eid' => string '423423' (length=6)
'pid' => string '23982938' (length=8)
'admin' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Not sure that is any faster though.

Comment: This is what you would do... if `parse_str` didn't exist. :)